# How to enable XA for Springboot H2 datasource?

Tags: spring-boot, h2, xa

What should I change in the below spring-boot H2 datasource config, **to make sure XA is enabled**?

```
@Bean
//@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource h2() {
    String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE";
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .url(url)
            .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
            .build();
}
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(h2())
            .packages("demo.h2xa.domain")
            .persistenceUnit("mydomainPersistanceUnit")
            .build();
}
```

Ref: http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.class as type helps.

```
public DataSource h2() {
    String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE";
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .url(url)
            .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
            .type(org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.class) //xa datasource
            .build();
}
```